# How to switch tasks between queues in Celery

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, message-queue, django-celery

I've got a couple of tasks in my `tasks.py` in Celery.

```
# this should go to the 'math' queue 
@app.task
def add(x,y):
    uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    result = x + y
    return {'id': uuid, 'result': result}

# this should go to the 'info' queue
@app.task
def notification(calculation):
    print repr(calculation)
```

What I'd like to do is place each of these tasks in a separate Celery queue and then assign a number of workers on each queue.

The problem is that I don't know of a way to **place a task** from one queue to another from within my code.

So for instance when an `add` task finishes execution I need a way to place the resulting python dictionary to the `info` queue for futher processing. How should I do that?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT -CLARIFICATION-**

As I said in the comments the question essentially becomes how can a worker place data retrieved from `queue A` to `queue B`.

Comment: celery task objects comes with `apply_async` method which can be used to specify the queue you want to send the task to by specifying the queue parameter  eg `getSystemInfo.apply_async(queue=queueList[i])`
you can aslo have the workers only listen on particular queues by the the adding the -Q option eg `--app=dir.app --loglevel=INFO -Q <queue-name>`. Once all this is done you just need some internal book keeing to understand which queue gets what task
``

Comment: @cmidi Fair enough. But essentially the question is how can a worker place data retrieved from `queue A` to `queue B`...

Comment: That is the reason I did not put it as the answer, I was not clear what the question is exactly. will the tasks always run one after the other or can they run concurrently on different queses ? do you want the result from one run task to be supplied to the other or you want the parameters ?

Comment: @cmidi You are right. The tasks should run asynchronously and concurrently on different queues. The `notification` task doesn't have to wait for the `add` result. However `add` should be able to post something  to `notification`'s queue so that its workers can pick it up and eventually display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this.

Wherever you calling the task,you can assign task to which queue.

```
add.apply_async(queue="queuename1")

notification.apply_async(queue="queuename2")
```

By this way you can put tasks in seperate queue.

**Worker for seperate queues**

```
celery -A proj -Q queuename1 -l info

celery -A proj -Q queuename2 -l info
```

But you must know that `default` queue is `celery`.So if any tasks without specifying `queue name` will goto `celery` queue.So A consumer for `celery` is needed if any like.

```
celery -A proj -Q queuename1,celery -l info
```

**For your expected answer**

If you want to pass result of one task to another.Then

```
result = add.apply_async(queue="queuename1")
result = result.get() #This contain the return value of task
```

Then

```
notification.apply_async(args=[result], queue="queuename2")
```

Comment: Yes, but how will the data transfer occur? I mean how `queuname2` will retrieve the returned dictionary (from `queuename1` in my example)?

Comment: Great. One more thing: Is there a way to preserve the task `id`? To give you an example it would be great if this `result` could keep the same `id` throughout its entire processing cycle.

Comment: `result.id` will give you id

Comment: Yes but if I slightly change your last line of code to this `result2 = notification.apply_async(args=[result], queue="queuename2")`, then `result2.id` won't be the same as `result.id`.

Comment: isn't `result.get()` a blocking call ? this would make tasks run one after the other

Comment: No, it cant.If you want like that, You have to use custom task ids.

Comment: Yes `.get()` will wait for result.

Comment: Look at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives.This will help you